# Instead of FIrefox, Nighly browser launched with playwright java

Tags: playwright, playwright-java

I tried to launch Firefox with below code snippets in separate attempts with Playwright Java 1.33.0 version but , it just launches Nighly browser. it seems that is the intended behavior, anyway to overcome this?

```
browser = playwright.firefox().launch(new BrowserType.LaunchOptions().setHeadless(false));
    
Browser browser = playwright.firefox().launch(new BrowserType.LaunchOptions().setChannel("firefox").setHeadless(false));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playwright uses its own Firefox build. That build is based on the Firefox Nightly build. That's why you are getting that browser. You won't be able to use the stock browser version.